# Java won't export my resources properly

Tags: java, eclipse

So I have 2 class folders one is `res` the other is `lib`. My `res` folder has two other sub folders one with images the other with sounds. My `lib` folder has 4 other jar files and a native folder. It all works within eclipse but when I try to export it as a runnable jar it does not work. I won't won't recognize anything.

I am to call my images I am using `ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));` For the sound I am using the external libraries I mentioned earlier to load and play them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am to call my images I am using `ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath))`

Contrary to your title, this is *not* an Eclipse problem - it's simply a bug in your code, because your code assumes that the image is stored as a file in the file system, when it's not.

You don't *have* a file for the image, so you shouldn't use `new File`. You should instead use `Class.getResource` or `ClassLoader.getResource` - or the `getResourceAsStream` equivalents. That way, it will load the resource from whatever context the class itself is loaded, which is appropriate for jar files. So for example, you might have:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(MyClass.getResource("foo.png"));
```

... where `foo.png` is effectively in the same package structure as the class. Alternatively:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(MyClass.getResource("/images/foo/bar.png"));
```

where `images` is a folder within the root directory of one of your jar files loaded by the same `ClassLoader`. (We don't have enough information to give you complete code here, but that should be enough to get you going.)